# Can I use SQL cache dependency with SubSonic?

Tags: sql, subsonic, cache-dependency

I want to use SQL cache dependency with SubSonic. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt you can do that - the SQL cache dependency model is based on the SqlCommand object in ADO.NET - SubSonic totally replaces that. So unless there's something directly built into SubSonic (I don't know it well enough to answer that), I am afraid you're probably out of luck.

Marc